# Problem with change the Abstract name

Tags: errors, environments, templates, abstract, variant

I use the next enviroment for the abstract section:

```
\newcommand{\abstractname}{Prefacio}  
\makeatletter
\if@titlepage
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{flushleft}%
        \noindent \bfseries \Huge \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{flushleft}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\makeatother
```

But still put "Abstract" in the output. I'm working with documentclass type book.

Comment: As always on this site please post a full minimal example instead of sniplets like this. We for example would like to see if you're using babel as it controls how certain names are changed and when they are changed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If I make your code snippet compilable by prefixing it with `\documentclass{book}` and affixing `\begin{document} \begin{abstract} Hello World. \end{abstract} \end{document}`, LaTeX produces an unnumbered section-level header named `Prefacio`.